# How to make components in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am new to react native and want to create three Components. for Increment Button, Decrement Button and to display Counter value.
State/Hook should remain in the App Component. I don't want to Modify that.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
const [getIncCounter, setIncCounter] = useState(0)
const inc = () => {
setIncCounter(getIncCounter + 1);
}
const dec = () => {
setIncCounter(getIncCounter - 1);
}
return (
<View style={styles.container}>
  <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Button title="+" onPress={inc} />
    <Text> {getIncCounter} </Text>
    <Button title="-" onPress={dec} />
  </View>
 </View>
 );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
flex: 1,
justifyContent: 'center',
backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
padding: 8,
},
paragraph: {
margin: 24,
fontSize: 18,
fontWeight: 'bold',
textAlign: 'center',
},
});
```

Comment: What's not working for you now?

Comment: I don't know how to make components for these three functions. I don't want to change the state. It should remain in the app component.

Comment: Just make a component and give it as props the functions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can create a separate component for increase/decrease buttons and a component for showing results.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet, Button } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const [getIncCounter, setIncCounter] = useState(0);
  const inc = () => {
    setIncCounter(getIncCounter + 1);
  };
  const dec = () => {
    setIncCounter(getIncCounter - 1);
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
        <ButtonComponent title={'+'} onClick={inc} />
        <ResultComponent result={getIncCounter} />
        <ButtonComponent title={'-'} onClick={dec} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const ButtonComponent = ({ onClick, title }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Button title={title} onPress={onClick} />
    </div>
  );
};

const ResultComponent = ({ result }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Text> {result} </Text>
    </div>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
    padding: 8,
  },
  paragraph: {
    margin: 24,
    fontSize: 18,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

It's redundant though, but if you want to learn how to pass props and stuff it is fine. Button and Text are components themselves.

[Expo Snack Example](https://snack.expo.io/@xeteke8423/frisky-bananas)